# Configure Power BI Analysis Services Connector

Tags: ssas, powerbi, office365connectors

I am configuring the Power BI Analysis Services Connector but getting the below error

"the remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. [REQUESTID: e202c423-cd6a-4fd8-ae27-9b8b5231d433] [UTC TIMESTAMP: 01-03-2016 13:43:47] [CLUSTER: wabi-south-east-asia-redirect.analysis.windows.net]"

[image]

Did anyone has the solution of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain. I also struggled with this for about a day. I then saw a small post on a support site that the Power Bi Analysis connector was actually replaced with a new piece of software called: Power BI gateway for enterprise deployments
you can find it here: 
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-preview-of-power-bi-gateway-for-enterprise-deployments/

It's a joke how easy it was to set up the connection after installing that.
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Terence for the reply, and yes it is really a joke, once I set the enterprise gateway, things moving like a charm.